# ogr2ogr "Error: pointer being freed was not allocated" on mac mavericks

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, mac

I've successfully installed `GDAL` via homebrew on mac

But while I'm using command `ogr2ogr`, keep getting error below

```
$ ogr2ogr -f geoJSON tl_2010_20_tract10.json tl_2010_20_tract10.shp

CPLAcquireMutex: Error = 22CPLMutexHolder: Failed to acquire mutex!
ogr2ogr(2439,0x7fff7743a310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb7a0d00560: pointer being      freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    2439 abort      ogr2ogr -f geoJSON tl_2010_20_tract10.json tl_2010_20_tract10.shp
```

and it also happened while using `ogrinfo`.

Do anyone knows what this error means, and how could I fix it?